# Glyphicon's hover effect is offset - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with `:hover` on a `glyphicon` within a `span`.

I am not sure if the `glyphicon` is not filling the whole `span`, or if there are some hidden `paddings`/`margins` I am not seeing. I have tried to manual set all sorts of weird styles to get a nice glow border around my `glyphicon` but nothing is working.

**Image** (hovering over the gold color in this image)

[image]

**Example**

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KcqZD/)**

**CSS**

```
.glyphicon-stop:hover {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px yellow;
}
```

**View**

```
<div>
<p id="hoverColor" style="font-size: 12px; width: 110px; background: black; display: inline-block; text-align: center; color:white; margin:0px; padding:0px">Color Code</p>
</div>

<div id="colorCode" style="margin:0px; padding:0px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" id="_Group Event" style="color: red; font-size: 20px"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" id="_Misc. Event" style="color:orangered; font-size: 20px"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" id="_Online Event" style="color:purple; font-size: 20px"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" id="_Group Party" style="color:blue; font-size: 20px"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop" id="_Tournament" style="color:darkorange; font-size: 20px"></span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('[id^=_]').hover(function () {
    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
    document.getElementById("hoverColor").innerHTML = $(this).attr('id').replace('_', '');
}, function () {
    document.getElementById("hoverColor").innerHTML = "Color Code";
}
);
```

Any help on getting the border to be around JUST the `glyphicon` and not be offset would be appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behaviour (the fiddle) neither in chrome / FF on ubuntu nor chrome / IE on windows. The only issue is, that the border is not present in IE and FF, since you lack `box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow`

Comment: @davidkonrad Really? When I hover over the boxes in the Fiddle I get the same issue. Using Chrome.

Comment: yes, looks like this, for example, chrome / ubuntu -> http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dcahhc&s=8#.U7LD79RJXUY

Comment: @davidkonrad isn't that the same thing? It is still offset from the span (white space between glyphicon and glow). I would like the glow to be right on the edge of the square, not offset from it.

Comment: Yes, @Austin. Must admit I was not paying enough attention, my eyes are not what they used to be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution, more an explanation about what there is going on. The behaviour is caused by the fact, that the bootstrap glyphicons not is filling out the entire area. They have all some built in "margin" or "padding". In your case you are using the following glyph :

```
.glyphicon-stop:before {
   content: "\e074";
}
```

see all the glyphs here -> **http://www.bootply.com/61521**

here is a demonstration how much "margin" or "padding" the `\e074` "video stop" glyph contains :

your fiddle forked -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Ay9Mj/**

That matches, surprise surprise, your bad experience in the question. So the error is the glyphs themselves, not some bad CSS or errors in the markup. I would suggest you go away from the "video stop" glyph, and use a fair square icon or simply just a rectangular `<span>`. Why use those glyphs anyway, when you just want to show a square?

Comment: I figured it was the glypicons. haha I decided to go with a `css`-based box as well. Thanks!